# How do I access data for all of my students?

Tags: khan-academy

I'm making an app that authenticates a coach with KA's API, in order to present statistics and reports on the progress of each student.

How do I see "For whom am I a coach" (inverse of `/api/v1/user.coaches`)?

or otherwise request user and progress data for all my students?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request `/api/v1/user/students` to get a list of the currently authenticated users' students. Note that this is an undocumented endpoint, not sure if that's on purpose or not, but I suspect just an oversight because IIRC I've seen them reference it on github issues in the past.

I added that endpoint to the `khan` npm module in this PR: https://github.com/weo-edu/khan/pull/4

An important caveat to note is that as of this writing, you won't be able to request students on behalf of a user who has authenticated your application, only the user who created the app you're currently using.

Put another way: If I create an application called "hello" while logged in as "Jeffrey", I can get all of Jeffrey's students by authenticating with the "hello" app. However, If I log in as Lisa via the "hello" app (via oauth, e.g. [passport-khan](https://github.com/jesseditson/passport-khan)), I'll have an access token but the Khan API will refuse my request because Lisa did not create the "hello" app.

This behavior is documented (albeit a bit confusingly) in [this wiki page](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Recommended-Practices), here's the relevant paragraph:

> It is recommended that schools have one teacher/coach account that registers for an API key. This enables a situation where the logged-in user is the same as the third-party developer, who then can access their own students' data pursuant to Khan Academy's "coach" relationship. For example, suppose the principal of Riverdale High wished to export data for multiple students via the API. The principal would create a teacher/coach account, perhaps called "RiverdaleHighAPI," and register for an API key. The principal would then ask all students of Riverdale High to add "RiverdaleHighAPI" as a coach, either directly or via several class codes. When accessing the API with "RiverdaleHighAPI" as the logged in user, the principal would be able to access the data for all students that have added "RiverdaleHighAPI" as a coach. The app would not have access to any other coaches' student data, even if another coach logged in through the app. To protect student privacy, we do not allow indirect consent through the coach, and we require each student to explicitly grant permission to access their data. Please note that we are working to improve this functionality; for the time being, this "RiverdaleHighAPI" account should only be used by the school's API client, not by any actual teacher or coach.

Lastly, **khan actually encourages public use of their internal API**. They recommend opening up your developer console while logged in to khan and looking for the endpoints that return the data you want. (see [this note on their authentication document](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/wiki/Khan-Academy-API-Authentication#the-endpoints-exposed-on-the-api-explorer-dont-seem-to-do-what-i-need-am-i-ableallowed-to-access-any-other-endpoints)).
This is obviously a fairly non-standard practice and I assume the endpoints would be subject to breaking changes without warning. Also you'll be flying documentation free. That said, this approach may be the most robust option for your purposes. Here's the quote from their wiki for posterity:

> The API explorer documents our public API, which has URLs starting with /api/v1, but unfortunately it's not very well-maintained and lacking in a few areas.
>
> If you're feeling adventurous, though, you're welcome to use any internal undocumented API endpoints. For example, if you load a Khan Academy video page and use your browser's developer tools to look at the ajax requests being sent, you'll see that it gets a URL like /api/internal/videos/aubZU0iWtgI/transcript, which contains a JSON response with the video subtitles. That "internal" in the name means that we don't provide documentation, and we may remove the endpoint or change the format in the future, but you're welcome to use any internal endpoints if you keep those caveats in mind.

Comment: I find it quite disturbing that an API is implemented without it even being properly documented. Even more so that the documentation is outdated - changes to an API should be in a new version! If you want to encourage the public to use an API, it should be properly documented and stable.