# Authenticating Student Accounts with Khan Academy API

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, google-oauth, khan-academy, oauth-1.0a

I am writing a Google Apps Script to access student information from Khan Academy through their API. Currently, I have a script that successfully accesses MY user data and lists my students' information as JSON data. I can access their user ids and keys but I am not sure how to proceed to access information like their weekly progress and exercise summaries. How can I switch the OAuth to access their accounts using api/user/exercises? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below.

```
var CONSUMER_KEY = 'my consumer key';
var CONSUMER_SECRET = 'my consumer secret';
var PROJECT_KEY = 'my project key';


function listExercises() {
  var service = getKhanAcademyService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
     var response = service.fetch('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/v1/user/students');
     var students = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
     Logger.log(students);
     Logger.log("______________________________");

     for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++){
       Logger.log(students[i].nickname + ": " + students[i].user_id);
       Logger.log(students[i].student_summary.key);

     //HERE I WANT TO ACCESS MORE DETAILED STUDENT INFORMATION, LIKE THEIR
     //MASTERED SKILLS AND WEEKLY PROGRESS

}

  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.authorize();
    Logger.log('Please visit the following URL and then re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }
}

function getKhanAcademyService() {
  var service = OAuth1.createService('khanAcademy');


    service.setAccessTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/access_token');
service.setRequestTokenUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/request_token')   
service.setAuthorizationUrl('https://www.khanacademy.org/api/auth2/authorize');
service.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
service.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
service.setCallbackFunction('authCallback');
service.setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties());
service.setOAuthVersion('1.0a');
service.setParamLocation('uri-query');
return service;
    }

function authCallback(request) {
  var service = getKhanAcademyService();
  var isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this page');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this page');
  }
}
```

Comment: You may refer with this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420320/how-do-i-access-data-for-all-of-my-students). It stated that you can request `/api/v1/user/students` to get a list of the currently authenticated users' students. You may check this [Khan Academy API Explorer](https://api-explorer.khanacademy.org/).

Comment: I've already got that working in the code posted above. This returns a list of all of my current students with some key information about them, but not the specific information I am looking for. I want student's detailed weekly progress reports which I cannot access from there.